# When trying to configure pcb-2011-018 for OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), config reports that it can't find openGL library?

Tags: c, opengl, osx-snow-leopard, autotools

How do I get configure to see the openGL library? It is seeing the openGL headers.

Answer (score 0):

Check `config.log` to see which test program failed to compile.  Then change whatever you need to ensure that program compiles.

Comment: conftest.c :-) failed to compile (of course) The following is what the config log reports.
configure:12790: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -g -O2 -I/opt/local/include -D_THREAD_SAFE  -L/opt/local/lib -rdynamic  -dylib_file /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib conftest.c -lopengl32  >&5
ld: library not found for -lopengl32
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status